# Xcode 6 not resizing app correctly on different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have just transitioned over to Xcode 6 and am having a problem already. Whenever I launch the app in any of the simulators, the app resizes to fit the screen. But when I run the app on my iPhone 5, there is about 1-2 inches of black space above and below the main view controller thus it not filling up the entire screen like it should. I have not changed any settings so I have no idea what is causing it not to work. To make sure it was nothing I did, I created a completely blank app and ran it on my iPhone 5 and it does the same exact thing. If any body else has experienced this problem and knows what is happening, I would greatly appreciate a response!

Thanks in advance, I'll be sure to reward whatever answer helps me!

Edit: After updating my iPhone 5 to iOS 8, the problem no longer persists. This still worries because I do not want my iOS 7 to encounter this problem. Also, if this question is a duplicate (which it is not, because I have spent an hour on here looking for solutions but nothing was found), then please refer me to the question that was previously asked. It does no good to me or anybody who stumbles upon this question if you don't provide a link to the previous one.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as this is a new issue with the universal storyboard in Xcode 6